# 公開してはいけない情報を質問や回答として投稿してしまいました。どうすれば良いですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問

アクセスキーや顧客の実データなど、本来であれば公開してはいけないセンシティブな情報を質問や回答として投稿してしまいました。どうすれば良いでしょうか？

---

関連: [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/341401)

[←FAQ目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 7):

### まず、投稿を編集してセンシティブな情報を除いてください

こうすることでその情報が目に入るユーザーの数を減らすことができ、影響を小さく留めることができます。

編集をする際、センシティブな情報が入ってしまったということを編集サマリーに書いてください。また、編集が注目を集めることを避けるため、このことを通常のコメントとして投稿することは控えてください。

例外的に、投稿の[編集権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)を持っていない場合があるかもしれません。この場合、編集を提案することができます。この際、**センシティブな情報を全て削除編集しているか確かめてください。** そうでないと、この編集提案が他の方のもっと適切な編集を妨げてしまいますし、また、もしかすると「提案された編集の履歴」に情報の痕跡を残してしまうかもしれません。

### 続いて、モデレーターによる対応が必要であるとして投稿を通報し、センシティブな情報を削除すべき理由を説明してください

単に投稿を編集するだけだと、編集履歴に情報が残ってしまいます。アクセスキーが漏れてしまった場合では結局キーを再生成することになるので単なる編集で充分かもしれませんが、そうでない場合は困ります。編集履歴からも情報を取り除きたい場合、**モデレーターであれば "redact" という作業を行うことで個別の編集履歴を削除できます。** モデレーターに問題を伝えて redact を行ってもらうため、通報機能を使ってください。

もしあなたの信用度が 15 未満で[投稿を通報する権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)を持っていない場合、ページフッターにある「問い合わせ先」のフォームから Community Team に連絡を取ってください。この連絡は Stack Exchange の社員にのみ送られ、モデレーターを含む他のユーザーには一切通知されません。

### モデレーターの方へ: redact のやり方

通報された部分が確かに公開されるべきではなさそうな場合、その情報を含んでいる各リビジョンに対して "redact" (修正) をしてください。通常 "redact" ボタンは全てのリビジョンに表示されていますが、その情報が削除されたリビジョンより古いリビジョンに対して操作を行えば良いです。

[image: 修正ボタンの場所のスクリーンショットです]

一人のモデレーターが redact を行ったあと、別のモデレーターがその redact を承認することが必要です。これは通報キューから見つかるはずです。こうすることでこの機能が軽く使われることや、間違って使って良い編集を消してしまうことを防いでいます。他のモデレーターの redact を承認する際、もしその redact が適切でないように見えたなら、そのモデレーターとコミュニケーションを取ってください。

もしセンシティブな情報をすぐに redact できなさそうであれば、redact できるまで投稿自体を削除しておくこともできます。