# ヘルプセンター翻訳 "I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?"

Tags: サポート, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

この投稿は [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) の翻訳案です。

---

**質問を取り消したいですが削除しても良いですか？**

投稿した後に考えが変わることがあるかも知れません。求職に関する質問を同僚に見られたくない、投稿すべきでなかったプロプライエタリなコードに気がついた、或いはあなたの愚かなミスを友達に見られたくない等、様々な理由が考えられます。**もしまだ誰も回答していないなら、そのまま[削除して](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)も構いません。誰も気にする人はいないでしょう。**

もしあなたの質問に良い回答がついている場合、それらの回答ごと削除してしまうのは公平ではありません。他のユーザーがあなたを助けるために労力を割いたわけですし、もう*あなたには*必要ない回答だとしても、他のユーザーには必要かも知れません。そのため、大概の場合、回答がついた質問を削除しようとするとシステムに止められます。

ですが、いくつかできることもあります。

- あなたの質問が不必要に詳細な場合は、**編集**して一般化しましょう。具体的な雇用者名、ベンダ名などの詳細は本当に必要ですか？あなたの居場所は、実際のところ重要なものですか？変数名をつけ直してコードをより一般化できませんか？既存の回答を無意味にしてしまったり、答えようのない曖昧すぎる質問にならないよう気をつける必要はありますが、もしその質問をしうる人があなた以外にもたくさんいるようにできれば、それがあなただとは誰もわからないでしょう。**ほとんどの場合、編集を行うだけで十分です。**
- もし本当に、特定されかねない詳細を取り除いていったら質問がどうしようもなくなってしまい、しかもどの回答も多くの投票を集めていないとき、とりわけ質問がクローズ済の場合には、通報によってモデレーターに削除を依頼することができます。あまり多くのものが失われない場合は、質問を消してくれるかもしれません。(訳注:ここ自信なし)
- もし、絶対に機密であるべき情報、例えばパスワードやAPIキーを投稿してしまった場合、即座に編集で消してから、[モデレーターに通報し、**履歴の削除(redact)**](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3004/14055) を依頼してください。この時、何をどうするべきかと(もし自明でなければ)その理由も明確にしましょう。履歴の削除(redact)依頼は2人のモデレーターによる承認が必要なので少し時間がかかる場合もあります。質問がクローズ済の場合、モデレーター次第では質問そのものを消してしまうかもしれません。履歴の削除(redact)を受けても質問や回答が無意味にならないような投稿方法についてのより詳細なガイドは、[この記事](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327142/how-do-i-get-my-post-deleted-as-quickly-as-possible-since-it-is-someones-ip/327145#327145)をご覧ください。
- 質問はよいもので、機密情報もないけれど、*内容に自分の名前が含まれてしまっていた*、という場合には、[アカウントから切り離す](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-3-0)ことができるかもしれません。これは真の匿名*ではありません*。一度インターネットに投稿したものは、どこかには永久に残り続けます。依頼はレビューされるため、少々時間がかかります。ひとたび依頼が承認されれば、元に戻すことはできません。

履歴の削除(redact)や切り離しが許されているとはいえ、これは稀な例外であり通常ではありません。投稿しては履歴の削除(redact)や切り離しを何度も繰り返し依頼するような投稿パターンはアカウント停止に繋がります。一度書いたものは永久に公開され続けると思って投稿しましょう。

荒らしや、有用な投稿の大量削除を行うと、システム的な警告をトリガーし、モデレーションチームからのアクションを引き起こすことになります。他者の労力に敬意を持ちましょう。つまり、その成果を無に帰するようなことは避け、迷惑をかけないようにしましょう。

**上述したいずれも、システムによる投稿ブロックの解除には利用できません。** もしあなたが新たな質問や回答の投稿をブロックされていて、投稿ブロックを解除してほしいなら、[私のアカウントからの質問が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) や [私のアカウントからの回答が受け付けられなくなったのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) を参照してください。

Comment: "redact"は現状「修正」と訳しているのですが、日本語としてはあまりに一般的な言葉なので私が使うときはそのままredactと言ってしまっています。ここでは「修正（redact）」と補足付きで訳すのはいかがでしょうか？　redactのもっと良い訳があれば良いのですが……。

Comment: 見出しの訳についてですが、"think better of ..." は「考えを改め～を取り消す」という意味だと思うので、「質問を取り消したいですが、削除しても良いですか？」というように、もう少し直接的な (見出しとして目立つ？) 表現にしても良いかな、と思いました。

Comment: 「redact」は「履歴の削除」なども候補として。Google翻訳だと「墨消し」となりますが、イメージは一番近いかも。 / 実行できるのは実質モデレーターだけに限られているので、ヘルプの説明では強くこだわらず、より分かりやすい表現に置き換えてもいいかもしれません。

Comment: 「編集履歴から削除するように依頼してください」では駄目でしょうか？あと、元のヘルプから変わってしまいますが「https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3004/」を モデレーター～redact にリンク貼りたいです。そうすれば意味が分からなかったらリンクを辿るのでは？と思いました。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん、supaさん、cubickさん、Siegさんのコメントに基づき一旦変更いたしました。今現在、Traducirでは [redact=修正](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%28%3Fi%29redact) と訳されております。

Answer (score 3):

翻訳が固まり、vote も充分あるようでしたので、翻訳をヘルプページに反映しました。タイトルはモデレーターでは弄れないので、変更されるのを今しばらくお待ちください。　→　タイトルも反映されました

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question